# Google Drive API v3 VB.NET Upload and Download Files to ServiceAccount

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, c#-to-vb.net

I've been trying to follow https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet and the Google API documentation, as well as searching all over the internet, but there really isn't a straightforward example to use (especially for v3)

I have a VB.NET GUI that contains a listview with the names of all plain text files in a folder. Clicking on one will display its' contents in a textbox. You can also type into a blank text box and save it. I want to allow multiple users to upload their text file to the Google Drive and be able to download all text files that are stored there.

I don't have much of an issue translating code from C# to VB.NET, and I think I'm fine with authenticating the service account with Google (or at least I don't get an error), but uploading only shows me response = Nothing. Any help is appreciated.

I created the service account through Google and have the following:

```
Dim service = AuthenticateServiceAccount("xxxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\accountkey-0c1aa839896b.json")
If drive.UploadFile(service, "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\file.txt") Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("File not uploaded")
Else
    MsgBox("File uploaded")
End If
```

Authenticate:

```
Public Function AuthenticateServiceAccount(ByVal serviceAccountEmail As String, ByVal serviceAccountCredentialFilePath As String) As DriveService
        Dim scopes As String() = {DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly, DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly, DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts}

    Try
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)) Then
                Throw New Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.")
        End If
        If Not IO.File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath) Then
            Throw New Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail)) Then
            Throw New Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.")
        End If

        If (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() = ".json") Then
            Dim credential As GoogleCredential
            Dim sstream As New FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(sstream)
            credential.CreateScoped(scopes)

            'Create the  Analytics service.
            Return New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = "Drive Service Account Authentication Sample"
            })
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.")
        End If

    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("Create service account DriveService failed" + e.Message)
        Throw New Exception("CreateServiceAccountDriveFailed", e)
    End Try

End Function
```

Upload File:

```
Public Function UploadFile(service As DriveService, FilePath As String) As Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
        Dim body As New Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
        body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
        body.Description = "Text file"
        body.MimeType = "text/plain"

        'files content
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
        Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)

        Try
            Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, "text/plain")
            request.Upload()
            Return request.ResponseBody
        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    Else
        MsgBox("File does not exist: " + FilePath)
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218662/5832311), since you are using a Service Account, all the folders and files will be created in this Service Account's Drive which cannot be accessed through a web UI and will be limited to the default quota.

> To add content in a user's Drive, you will need to go through the regular OAuth 2.0 flow to retrieve credentials from this user. You can find more information about OAuth 2.0 on this pages:
>
> - [Retrieve and use OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials).
> - [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart): it has a quickstart sample in C# that you could use.
> - [Using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

You may also check this related thread: [upload files to Google drive in VB.NET - searching for working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003327/upload-files-to-google-drive-in-vb-net-searching-for-working-code)

Comment: I am fine with those limitations of a Service Account; I don't need to access anything through a web UI.

I would like all users to upload/download to the same drive, and I read that the only way this was achievable was through the Service Account and not using OAuth 2.0.

In the meantime, I have successfully uploaded/downloaded a text file using OAuth 2.0. Is having the Client ID and Client Secret hardcoded enough to allow multiple users access to the same storage? Even if there was a way to manually give access to each user's' email address through the drive, that would be sufficient.

Comment: Found the link explaining why I should be using a Service Account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587763/how-to-provide-credentials-programmatically-to-use-google-drive-api-in-c-sharp-o