# Get picture URL in google drive

Tags: vb.net, image, url, google-drive-api

I want to get an URL of picture exist in google drive and show it in forms , I try this method but always in nothing 
Here is my code

```
.....
CreateService()
    Dim tab() As String = fichier.Split(".")
    Dim list = Service.Files.List()
    list.Q = "trashed=false"
    list.Fields = "nextPageToken, items(id, title)"
    Dim count = list.Execute()
    For Each fich In count.Items
        If (fich.Title) = fichier Then

            Dim path As String = fich.WebContentLink
            Dim MyWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = MyWebClient.DownloadData(path)
            Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)
                affich_image.image.Image = New 
             System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)
       end if
```

fich.WebContentLink his value is nothing 
fichier is string , 
name of file exist in gridview

Comment: couldnt you use the google api, download the picture to a temp folder and have it load to your picture box from there? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working vb.net code for Drive v2 & OAuth 2.0 from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646527/upload-and-download-to-google-drive-using-vb-net-form):

```
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks

    Imports Google
    Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
    Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
    Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
    Imports Google.Apis.Services

    Imports Google.Apis.Auth
    Imports Google.Apis.Download

     'Dev Console:
     'https://console.developers.google.com/

     'Nuget command:
     'Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2

    Private Service As DriveService = New DriveService

    Private Sub CreateService()
    If Not BeGreen Then
        Dim ClientId = "your client ID"
        Dim ClientSecret = "your client secret"
        Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result
        Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "Google Drive VB Dot Net"})
    End If
End Sub


    Private Sub UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    If Service.ApplicationName <> "Google Drive VB Dot Net" Then CreateService()

    Dim TheFile As New File()
    TheFile.Title = "My document"
    TheFile.Description = "A test document"
    TheFile.MimeType = "text/plain"

    Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
    Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)

    Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MsgBox("Upload Finished")
End Sub

    Private Sub DownloadFile(url As String, DownloadDir As String)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    If Service.ApplicationName <> "Google Drive VB Dot Net" Then CreateService()

    Dim Downloader = New MediaDownloader(Service)
    Downloader.ChunkSize = 256 * 1024 '256 KB

    ' figure out the right file type base on UploadFileName extension
    Dim Filename = DownloadDir & "NewDoc.txt"
    Using FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(Filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim Progress = Downloader.DownloadAsync(url, FileStream)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Do While Progress.Status = TaskStatus.Running
        Loop
        If Progress.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
            MsgBox("Downloaded!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Downloaded :(")
        End If
    End Using
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

To get the URL, here is the code:

```
    Dim Request = Service.Files.List()
    Request.Q = "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false"
    Request.MaxResults = 2
    Dim Results = Request.Execute
    For Each Result In Results.Items
        MsgBox(Result.DownloadUrl & vbCrLf & Result.Title & vbCrLf & Result.OriginalFilename)
    Next
```

For further insight of what you needed, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet).