# upload large size file to google drive using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

my code is working for only less then 5 mb file but when i am trying with more the 5 mb file getting exception.

```
Private Sub UploadFile()
        If service.ApplicationName <> "Google Drive" Then CreateService()
        Dim thefile As New File With {
            .Name = fileName,
            .Description = "A Backup File",
            .MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
        }
        Dim uploadrequest As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload
        Dim bytearry As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
        Try
            Using stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytearry, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
                uploadrequest = service.Files.Create(thefile, stream, "application/octet-stream")
                uploadrequest.Fields = "id"

                'MsgBox(uploadrequest.GetProgress.Status.ToString())
                uploadrequest.Upload()
            End Using
            Dim file As File = uploadrequest.ResponseBody
            My.Settings.lastFileUploaded = fileName
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error Upload Failed:" + ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
        MsgBox("upload Finished`enter code here` " + file.Id)enter code here
    End Sub
```

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphnl.png)

Comment: *getting exception* is not a problem description that is useful unless we know specifically what that *exception* is. The information is on the screen right in front of you; unfortunately, we cannot see your screen from here, so you need to give us the information in your question itself. You're asking us for free help to solve your problem - you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the information you have available to use. Please [edit] your post to provide the **exact** exception message that you're getting. The *real* exception message, not your own *error* one.

Comment: I don't see any overload for the constructor of a MemoryStream that matches `Using stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytearry, System.IO.FileMode.Open)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25883233/8367626